# Getting hover to work on radio buttons using javascript in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a search, and when the user searches there will be a list of hotel names and their images shown.

I am trying to get a radio button to work, so the user can select the hotel they want to go to. However, for example if I click on the first hotel, and then click on the second hotel the first hotel is still selected.. I want the user to be able to chose one hotel. I also only want the radio button to appear once the user hovers over the hotel. But at the minute it is being shown at all time. If anyone could help me out with these issues it would be great, thanks.

Below is Javascript code

```
function gethotels(value) {
$.post("php/hotels.php", {
search: value
}, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if(data.results.length === 0)
      $("#hotels").html(data.error);
  else {
      $('#hotels').html('');
      for(var i=0; i<data.results.length; i++) {
        $('#hotels').append(createHotelSearchResult(data.results[i]));
      }
  }
  });
};

function createHotelSearchResult(hotelData) {
var radio = document.createElement("input");
var hotel = document.createElement('div');
var hotelName = document.createElement('h5');
hotelName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hotelData.hotel_name));
var hotelImg = document.createElement('img');
hotelName.className = 'hotelName';
hotelImg.className = 'hotelImg';
hotelImg.src = hotelData.image;
radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
radio.className = 'radiobtn';
hotel.appendChild(hotelName);
hotel.appendChild(hotelImg);
hotel.appendChild(radio);
return hotel;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#searchHotel').on('input', function(hotel) {
    gethotels(hotel.target.value);
   });
}); 

function toggleHotel() {
        var toggleHotel = $(hotel);

        if (toggleHotel.is(':visible')) {
            toggleHotel.hide();
        } else {
            toggleHotel.show();
        }

        $('#radiobtn').hover(toggleHotel, toggleHotel);
hotel.addEventListener('hover', false);
    }
```

This is the HTML

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="searchHotel" class="form-control"/>
            <a href="#Hotels"><span class="input-group-addon" value="search" id="submit" name="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span></a>
    </div>   

    <div class="container prices" id="hotels"></div><!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`radio buttons` are used for an exclusive selection to be made from a group of options.

To know which `radio buttons` are in the same group you must give them the same `name` value.

So if you add the following into your `createHotelSearchResult` function anywhere after the definition of the 'radio' variable:

```
radio.name = "rdoSelectedHotel";
```

they will now be exclusive.

Regarding the 'hover' part of your question, although it can be done, hovering over an `image` to display a `radio button` for the user to select, would mean that when you weren't hovering over the `image`, you would then hide the `radio button`. How would the user select it?

If a user wishes to select something, it should remain visible as to what was selected and what else can be selected. Hiding the inputs from the user and showing them sometimes will just lead to confusion.

Comment: The first part worked great, thank you. Basically what I want is for a user to be able to select a hotel. I just dont like the look of radio buttons and will ruin the design of the page, thats why I want to have them not visible at all times. If there was any way to just select a hotel and there be a different coloured box around the one that is selected would be the ultimate goal, but I thought radio buttons would be easier, and didn't know how to go about the second option

Comment: Another idea might be to take the click on the hotel image and store the currently selected hotel in a variable if required. Place CSS border around the currently selected hotel, or place a small image or text at the top of the page indicating which one is selected.